# Facebook Graph C# SDK Ver 6.0: Unable to create event on App's Page

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I am converting a fully working C# Web Application from REST API to GRAPH API, using FB C# SDK 6.0. I have been able to obtain access token and post event to my "personal" Facebook page without problem. But I need to post the event to the Page associated with my Web Application (for which I am the Admin). I am totally at a loss as how to obtain the required access token, and construct the "fbClient.Post" call to create the event. I could find no relevant example with the SDK. And I have spent many hours researching this and other forums etc.

Any help or even clues would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A wealth of information is there for the reading:

https://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk

> NOTE: THIS SDK IS DEPRECATED. WE ARE KNOW LONGER SUPPORTING IT AND IT WILL BE MADE PRIVATE SOON.

And ...

> Most data accessible via the Graph API required an access token. This SDK does not include a method of getting a token from a user, as the best method will depend on what type of application is using it. A desktop application might show a popup browser window that loads the Facebook site, for example. You can read more about obtaining an access token in the authentication guide.