# Getting started Facebook API 

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i want to develop Desktop based application in wpf (c#). which will need option to login their facebook account too. so i have registered my app in fb developer site and download C# sdk with reference some stack overflow link. **which always give connection failed**

// code which i have used

```
 string APIKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["API_Key"];
    string APISecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["API_Secret"];

Facebook.Session.ConnectSession connectsession = new Facebook.Session.ConnectSession(APIKey, APISecret);
if (connectsession.IsConnected())
            {
        Facebook.Rest.Api api = new Facebook.Rest.Api(connectsession);
        var friends = api.Friends.GetLists();
        foreach (var friend in friends)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(friend.name);
        }
}
```

**some site telling that C# sdk is deprecated.**

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/624/

[Facebook Graph C# SDK Ver 6.0: Unable to create event on App's Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965672/facebook-graph-c-sharp-sdk-ver-6-0-unable-to-create-event-on-apps-page)

please help me to start facebook api integration in my desktop based app using wpf. some body asked to use graph api but i have doubt whether this will supprot for c# . am struk to start my step on facebook integration.

Comment: Why not use the latest version of the C# Facebook SDK (http://docs.csharpsdk.org/) rather than the old archaic one?

Comment: @DMCS :i too searching the same .whether http://csharpsdk.org/  will help to use in Desktop based app? because there s no documentation for desktop APP. am new to C# plz provide some getting started document

Comment: this is where their documentation is located: http://docs.csharpsdk.org.

Answer (score 0):

Graph Api is fully supported in C#  because it is based on rest and you can call rest service through C# code, obviously url calling is different from method calling, In graph api you can call url and parse its response. I would recommend to go with graph api, Facebook has not provided the C# SDK, its a open source library maintained by open source community, however graph api help is directly provided by Facebook.

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721417/facebook-fan-page-app/10731744#10731744) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127143/which-sdk-to-use-for-asp-net-with-facebook/10583352#10583352) to know how to call graph api through C#

Comment: Graph api is rest based, u can call rest based methods from code behind, but call will be synchronous